# Symfony List of all kernel parameters available like %kernel.debug%

Tags: symfony

How can I get a list of all kernel parameters that are available for use in my configuration files. E.g., in config.yml I know I can access %kernel.debug% which either returns true or false depending on AppKernel's initialization in the app.php (or app_dev.php) file.

Comment: Do you want to access *one* specific parameter or really get a list of all of them?

Comment: Actually, I am trying to understand where and how is this %kernel% defined or loaded by symfony, and what all methods or property values are available for use in my configuration files

Answer (score 33, accepted):

**>=3.0 (or lower if using 3.0 directory structure)**

List all parameters in the container
`php bin/console debug:container --parameters`

For *nix use grep to limit results
`php bin/console debug:container --parameters | grep kernel`

View a specific parameter
`php bin/console debug:container --parameter=kernel.debug`

---

**>=2.6 <3.0 (if not using 3.0 directory structure)**

List all parameters in the container
`php app/console debug:container --parameters`

For *nix use grep to limit results
`php app/console debug:container --parameters | grep kernel`

View a specific parameter
`php app/console debug:container --parameter=kernel.debug`

---

**>=2.3 <=2.5**

List all parameters in the container
`php app/console container:debug --parameters`

For *nix use grep to limit results
`php app/console container:debug --parameters | grep kernel`

View a specific parameter
`php app/console container:debug --parameter=kernel.debug`

Comment: In symfony 2.5.  The command is `app/console container:debug --parameters`

Comment: Symfony 3.2 `php bin/console debug:container --parameters`

Comment: `php bin/console debug:container --parameter=kernel.debug` note no  's' at the end of the --parameter