# An exception occured in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [14] unable to open database file

Tags: mysql, angularjs, api, symfony

i had this error when i want to create a new database with wamp server.how can i solve

> $ app/console doctrine:database:create Could not create database
>   "symfony" for connection named default An exception occured in driver:
>   SQLSTATE[HY000] [14] unable to open database file

```
parameters.yml:
    database_driver: pdo_sqlite
    database_host: 127.0.0.1
    database_port: null
    database_name: symfony
    database_user: root
    database_password: null
    database_path: '%kernel.root_dir%/data/blog.sqlite'
    mailer_transport: smtp
    mailer_host: 127.0.0.1
    mailer_user: null
    mailer_password: null
    locale: en
    secret: secret_value_for_symfony_demo_application
```

parameters.yml.dist:

```
 # This file defines the canonical configuration parameters of the application.
    # Symfony uses this file as a template to generate the real app/config/parameters.yml
    # used by the application.
    # See 

http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/configuration.html#canonical-parameters
    parameters:
        # this demo application uses an embedded SQLite database to simplify setup.
        # in a real Symfony application you probably will use a MySQL or PostgreSQL database
    database_driver:   pdo_sqlite
    database_host:     127.0.0.1
    database_port:     ~
    database_name:     symfony
    database_user:     root
    database_password: ~
    # the 'database_path' is only used for SQLite type databases
    database_path:     %kernel.root_dir%/data/blog.sqlite

    # Uncomment these lines to use a MySQL database instead of SQLite:
    #
    # database_driver: pdo_mysql
    # database_host: 127.0.0.1
    # database_port: null
    # database_name: symfony_demo
    # database_user: root
    # database_password: null
    #




 # You can even create the database and load the sample data from the command line:
#
# $ cd your-symfony-project/
# $ php app/console doctrine:database:create
# $ php app/console doctrine:schema:create
# $ php app/console doctrine:fixtures:load





# If you don't use a real mail server, you can send emails via your Gmail account.
    # see http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/email/gmail.html
mailer_transport:  smtp
mailer_host:       127.0.0.1
mailer_user:       ~
mailer_password:   ~

# The code of the default language used by the application ('en' = English)
locale: en

# The 'secret' value is a random string of characters, numbers and symbols
# used internally by Symfony in several places (CSRF tokens, URI signing,
# 'Remember Me' functionality, etc.)
# see: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#secret
secret: 'secret_value_for_symfony_demo_application'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One reason why this message occurs, is when the user can't create a file in the `%kernel.root_dir%/data/` folder. Check if you can create a file inside this folder.

Comment: where i found this folder   ?

Comment: "kernel.root_dir" resolves to the directory containing the AppKernel class (usually "app"). So, you're looking for the directory ./app/data. Make sure it exists and that your web app has the rights to write inside.

Comment: Here are more information about available kernel parameters: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31339120/symfony-list-of-all-kernel-parameters-available-like-kernel-debug

Comment: @ Gildas in the directory ./app/data i don't have folder named data what can i do now ?

Comment: You may want to create this folder?

Comment: yes i will create this folder that's right @Markus?

Comment: And if you created this folder, does it solve the problem? Have you checked if the user can create a file inside the new folder?

Comment: the user can't create a file inside the new folder  how can i solve my problem @Markus

Comment: What is the operating system and on which user does you your app run?

Comment: windows 7 and this is the lien of github of project https://github.com/rsobon/Symfony-Rest-Angular-Demo @Markus

Answer (score 0):

i had this in config.yml @Markus

```
 doctrine:
        dbal:
            # instead of configuring the database access options in this file, we pull
            # them from the app/config/parameters.yml file. The reason is that config.yml
            # stores options that change the application behavior and parameters.yml
            # stores options that change from one server to another
            driver:   "%database_driver%"
            host:     "%database_host%"
            port:     "%database_port%"
            dbname:   "%database_name%"
            user:     "%database_user%"
            password: "%database_password%"
            charset:  UTF8
            # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver, add the path in parameters.yml
            # e.g. database_path: "%kernel.root_dir%/data/data.db3"




orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
    auto_mapping: true
```

Comment: Are you sure? You don't enable the `database_path` which is required if you are using sqlite. Try to remove the `#` for the `database_path`.